# Unity rendering twice at different positions does not work in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, render

I am trying to render at two different positions in the same frame using the same camera. It works in the built version but not the editor.

[Example] In a scene there are two boxes: red at <20, 0, 0> and blue <-120, 0, 0> (basically the blue box is behind the red box), first render() I set the clearflags to skybox, near_clip=0.3 and far_clip=40, then for the second render() I set clearflags to nothing, near_clip=40, far_clip=80 and I get the results bellow.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class RepeatingRendering : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Camera view distance
    public float g_view_dist = 80.0f;

    private Camera cam;
    private Vector3 pos;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = this.GetComponent<Camera>();
        cam.enabled = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        pos = this.transform.position;
        cam.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.Skybox;
        cam.nearClipPlane = 0.3f;
        cam.farClipPlane = 40.0f;
        cam.Render();
        cam.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.Nothing;
        this.transform.position -= new Vector3(120.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        cam.nearClipPlane = 40.0f;
        cam.farClipPlane = 80.0f;
        cam.Render();
        this.transform.position = pos;
        cam.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

[image: Left: Built | Right: Editor]
On the left is the built version which works well, on the right is the editor version which only captures the first Render() call. In the unity docs it says to disable the camera if your want to call Render manually, however that results in a screen that says: "scene is missing a fullscreen camera".

Is it possible to make it work in the editor with just one camera? if not, would I have two merge two framebuffers or something else to achieve this?

Comment: Try to move from `Update` to  `void OnPostRender()` and don't turn off camera.

Comment: It asks me to create a separate camera then: "Attempting to render from a camera that is currently rendering. Create a copy of the camera (Camera.CopyFrom) if you wish to do this.
UnityEngine.Camera:Render()"

Comment: What version of unity you are using? Also which platform: mac or win? I tested your code and didn't work at all, if I can put it like this, and I am using newest.

Comment: Using Windows 64bit, Unity 5.3.2f1 and as I stated it does not work unless you build it, which is the problem.

Comment: [Here is a low quality video](https://youtu.be/WRjj2NtSZ6E) to prove that it is working when built.

Comment: And [_this_](http://puu.sh/rrC1c/90d0d39205.png) is actually how far apart they are.